# Angular 2 + Bootstrap 3

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the standard way of integrating both angular and bootstrap 3?

Can I add the js files directly by including them in the index.html file of my project?

Also bootstrap 4 stable version is yet to be released. So I don't want to use it in my project. Please provide your inputs on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within `.angular-cli.json` you have two arrays: `styles` and `scripts`. You can add your static files there (no need to do this within the `index.html`).

Like this:

```
"styles": [
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Create a folder structure like following in your `src` folder

`assets`
  `> boostrap`

Drop the `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js` in that folder.

Then in `index.html` you can add them inside `<head></head>` following way:

```
<head>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

If you decide to use CDN, you don't need to create any folders, just put the links inside `<head></head>`

```
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `angular-cli` there is a npm package for bootstrap, then simply add the corresponding css and js files in your `.angular-cli.json` in the `scripts` and `styles` section.
Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli#global-library-installation

Comment: Thanks for your help